# Only allow access of FIle From embed

Tags: html, accessibility

So I am embedding a PDF file on my page:

```
<embed src="http://www.mywebsite.com/files/ebook.pdf" width="500" height="375">
```

Is there anyway to prevent any and all access to that file except for when it is being accessed via this embed?

Thanks!

Comment: Just for clarification...I don't even want the user to be able to type http://www.mywebsite.com/files/ebook.pdf in the browser window to get the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More elegant way would be to prevent access to that file or better directory from .htaccess file and only allow locally. Then your php script will acss the file when you need it. You can also force download from php.

See **[this](http://www.nopersonal.info/aboutkateers/php_stuff/php_force_download.php)** for php example.
And your .htaccess file will look like this and will reside in your restricted directory (where pdf is located):

```
#denies access to all but the allowed IP (presumably yours)
#all other users will be redirected to the ErrorDocument
ErrorDocument 403 http://www.example.com/your-login-page.php
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 76.117.227.192
```

Last line is your IP address (server) or put simply `Allow from localhost` instead. If somebody else will try to access the directory or files in it, they will be redirected to `ttp://www.example.com/your-login-page.php` with status code `403` (access forbidden). Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

you can use something can this from flashpaper from adobe http://www.adobe.com/products/flashpaper/ that way you can show your pdf files as flash embeddable but users cannot download it

Comment: Thanks for the answer Andy. I ended up going with FlexPaper.  flexpaper.devaldi.com/